# How to cancel an Asynchronous function in Swift

Tags: swift

In swift, what is the common practice to cancel an aync execution?

Using this example, which execute the closure asynchronously,
what is the way to cancel the async function?

```
func getSumOf(array:[Int], handler: @escaping ((Int)->Void)) {
    //step 2
    var sum: Int = 0
    for value in array {
        sum += value
    }
    //step 3
    Globals.delay(0.3, closure: {
        handler(sum)
    })
}

func doSomething() {
    //setp 1
    self.getSumOf(array: [16,756,442,6,23]) { [weak self](sum) in
        print(sum)
        //step 4, finishing the execution
    }
}
//Here we are calling the closure with the delay of 0.3 seconds
//It will print the sumof all the passed numbers.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no generalized answer to this question as it depends entirely upon your asynchronous implementation.

Let's imagine that your `delay` was the typical naive implementation:

```
static func delay(_ timeInterval: TimeInterval, closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + timeInterval) {
        closure()
    }
}
```

That's not going to be cancelable.

However you can redefine it to use `DispatchWorkItem`. This is cancelable:

```
@discardableResult
static func delay(_ timeInterval: TimeInterval, closure: @escaping () -> Void) -> DispatchWorkItem {
    let task = DispatchWorkItem {
        closure()
    }
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + timeInterval, execute: task)
    
    return task
}
```

By making it return a `@discardableResult`, that means that you can use it like before, but if you want to cancel it, grab the result and pass it along. E.g., you can define your asynchronous `sum` routine to use this pattern, too:

```
@discardableResult
func sum(of array: [Int], handler: @escaping (Int) -> Void) -> DispatchWorkItem {
    let sum = array.reduce(0, +)

    return Globals.delay(3) {
        handler(sum)
    }
}
```

Now, `doSomething` can, if it wants, capture the returned value and use it to cancel the asynchronously scheduled task:

```
func doSomething() {
    var task = sum(of: [16, 756, 442, 6, 23]) { sum in
        print(Date(), sum)
    }
    
    ...

    task.cancel()
}
```

---

You can also implement the `delay` with a `Timer`:

```
@discardableResult
static func delay(_ timeInterval: TimeInterval, closure: @escaping () -> Void) -> Timer {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: false) { _ in
        closure()
    }
}
```

And

```
@discardableResult
func sum(of array: [Int], handler: @escaping (Int) -> Void) -> Timer {
    let sum = array.reduce(0, +)

    return Globals.delay(3) {
        handler(sum)
    }
}
```

But this time, you'd `invalidate` the timer:

```
func doSomething() {
    weak var timer = sum(of: [16, 756, 442, 6, 23]) { sum in
        print(Date(), sum)
    }

    ...
    
    timer?.invalidate()
}
```

---

It must be noted that the above scenarios are unique to simple “delay” scenarios. This is not a general purpose solution for stopping asynchronous processes. For example, if the asynchronous tasks consists of some time consuming `for` loop, the above is insufficient.

For example, let's say you are doing something really complicated calculation in a `for` loop (e.g. processing the pixels of an image, processing frames of a video, etc.). In that case, because there is no preemptive cancelation, you'd need to manually check to see if the [`DispatchWorkItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchworkitem/1780829-iscancelled) or the [`Operation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/1408418-iscancelled) has been canceled by checking their respective `isCancelled` properties.

For example, let's consider an operation to sum all primes less than 1 million:

```
class SumPrimes: Operation {
    override func main() {
        var sum = 0
        
        for i in 1 ..< 1_000_000 {
            if isPrime(i) {
                sum += i
            }
        }
        
        print(Date(), sum)
    }
    
    func isPrime(_ value: Int) -> Bool { ... }   // this is slow
}
```

(Obviously, this isn't an efficient way to solve the “sum of primes less than *x*” problem, but it just an example for illustrative purposes.)

And

```
let queue = OperationQueue()
let operation = SumPrimes()
queue.addOperation(operation)
```

We're not going to be able to [`cancel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/1411672-cancel) that. Once it starts, there’s no stopping it.

But we can make it cancelable by adding a check for `isCancelled` in our loop:

```
class SumPrimes: Operation {
    override func main() {
        var sum = 0
        
        for i in 1 ..< 1_000_000 {
            if isCancelled { return }
            
            if isPrime(i) {
                sum += i
            }
        }
        
        print(Date(), sum)
    }
    
    func isPrime(_ value: Int) -> Bool { ... }
}
```

And

```
let queue = OperationQueue()
let operation = SumPrimes()
queue.addOperation(operation)

...

operation.cancel()
```

Bottom line, if it’s something other than a simple delay, and you want it to be cancelable, you have to integrate this into your code that can be run asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

> Using this example..., what is the way to cancel the async function?

Using that example, there is no such way. The only way to avoid printing the sum is for `self` to go out existence some time in the 0.3 seconds immediately after the call.

(There are ways to make a cancellable timer, but the timer *you've* made, assuming that it's the `delay` I think it is, is *not* cancellable.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your algorithm but first I have suggestions for some points.

- If you want to delay, do it outside of `getSumOf` function for adapt Single Responsibility.
- Use built-in `reduce` function to sum items in array in better and more efficient way.

You can use `DispatchWorkItem` to build a cancellable task. So you can remove `getSumOf` function and edit `doSomething` function like below.

```
let yourArray = [16,756,442,6,23]

let workItem = DispatchWorkItem {
    // Your async code goes in here
    let sum = yourArray.reduce(0, +)
    print(sum)
}

// Execute the work item after 0.3 second
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3, execute: workItem)

// You can cancel the work item if you no longer need it
workItem.cancel()
```

You can also look into [OperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue) for advanced use.